# In ryslog how to enable milliseconds for a specific local facility?

Tags: rsyslog

We need to enable milliseconds in only one specific facility of ryslog. I think $ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_FileFormat would enable milliseconds for all syslogs not to a specific local facility.
How to add this template just to a local facility of the below kind:

local5.*  /opt/logs/my_app.log

Answer (score 0):

You could create a named template, that outputs the milliseconds, and
them bind it to the action like:

```
local5.* /opt/logs/my_app.log;template-name
```

See this for further info: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-rsyslog-templates/